# Unable to solve this Complex Regex

Tags: php, regex

I have some examples like below. What I need is to remove the timing part in particular line. For example from:

> Uefa Europa League Simulcast 8.00am-10.00Am

I only need:

> Uefa Europa League Simulcast

I am new to regex. Can someone please guide me.

Below are some example strings I am working with:

- Uefa Europa League 8 Simulcast 8.00am-10.00Am
- MLB: Chicago White - Sox at Los Angeles Angels 8.00PM-11.00AM
- MLB Spring: Chicago Cubs at Los Angeles Dodgers 8.00aM-11.00PM
- Live Test Cricket New am Zealand v England: Second Test Day Two
  9:00am-5:00am
- UEFA Europa League Hightlights 10.00pm-11.00pm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php

$str = array("Uefa Europa League Simulcast 8.00am-10.00Am",
"MLB: Chicago White Sox at Los Angeles Angels 8.00PM-11.00AM",
"MLB Spring: Chicago Cubs at Los Angeles Dodgers 8.00aM-11.00PM",
"Live Test Cricket New Zealand v England: Second Test Day Two 9:00am-5:00am",
"UEFA Europa League Hightlights 10.00pm-11.00pm");


foreach ($str as $s) {
   $new = preg_replace('/\s*\d?\d[\.\:]\d\d[ap]m-\d?\d[\.\:]\d\d[ap]m\s*$/i', '', $s);
   echo "$new\n";
}
```

Outputs

```
Uefa Europa League Simulcast
MLB: Chicago White Sox at Los Angeles Angels
MLB Spring: Chicago Cubs at Los Angeles Dodgers
Live Test Cricket New Zealand v England: Second Test Day Two
UEFA Europa League Hightlights
```

Explanations of `/\s*\d?\d[\.\:]\d\d[ap]m-\d?\d[\.\:]\d\d[ap]m\s*$/i`

- `\s*` means zero or more whitespaces
- `\d?` means one or zero digit
- `\d` means a digit
- `[\.\:]` means `.` or `:`
- `[ap]` means `a` or `p`
- `$` means end of string
- `/.../i` means case insensitive

Comment: it is not working for 11.00PM-2.00AM ? can u add this too please

Comment: It is working for `11.00PM-2.00AM` (just tried in my code). Do you have a space before or after? Edited to take into account spaces before or after... Please try with new regexp

Answer (score 1):

No need for a regular expression - you can just trim the string at the last space:

```
<?php

$str = array(
    "Uefa Europa League Simulcast 8.00am-10.00Am",
    "MLB: Chicago White Sox at Los Angeles Angels 8.00PM-11.00AM",
    "MLB Spring: Chicago Cubs at Los Angeles Dodgers 8.00aM-11.00PM",
    "Live Test Cricket New Zealand v England: Second Test Day Two 9:00am-5:00am",
    "UEFA Europa League Hightlights 10.00pm-11.00pm"
);

foreach ($str as $s) {
    $trimmed = substr($s, 0, strrpos($s, ' '));
    echo "$trimmed\n";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions match only regular strings, so lets break down the example strings you have provided and look for some regularity:

```
8.00am-10.00Am
8.00PM-11.00AM
8.00PM-11.00AM
8.00PM-11.00AM
10.00pm-11.00pm
```

So I can see that:

- it always starts with either one or two digits. This can be expressed as `\d{1,2}`
- this is followed by either a dot `.` or a colon `:`. This can be expressed as `[.:]`
- this is always followed by 2 digits: `\d{2}`
- then either the string `AM` or `PM`, case insensitive. To use case-insensitivity, we can use the `i` modifier for the entire pattern, so we just need to match `am` or `pm`, written as `(am|pm)`. This will behave as a capturing group, and we don't need to capture, so we can optimise the expression with `(?:am|pm)`, a non-capturing group
- then a dash `-`, this can be expressed literally
- then the first part of the pattern is repeated.

So when we put it all together, we get:

```
/\d{1,2}[.:]\d{2}(?:am|pm)-\d{1,2}[.:]\d{2}(?:am|pm)/i
```

But wait... this will leave trailing whitespace on the end of the subject string. Well, we could just `trim()` this off, but we can also get the regular expression to handle this for us, by prepending `\s*` to the pattern.

```
/\s*\d{1,2}[.:]\d{2}(?:am|pm)-\d{1,2}[.:]\d{2}(?:am|pm)/i
```

So now we just need to replace anything that matches this pattern with an empty string. You can do this in PHP with `preg_replace()`:

```
$pattern = '/\s*\d{1,2}[.:]\d{2}(?:am|pm)-\d{1,2}[.:]\d{2}(?:am|pm)/i';
$string = 'Uefa Europa League Simulcast 8.00am-10.00Am';

$string = preg_replace($pattern, '', $string);

var_dump($string);
```

[See it working](http://codepad.org/LlmkmPKa)